# SSL Certificate Verify Failed on Python in Office Network

Tags: python-3.x

Can you suggest a workaround on the SSL Certificate Verification Failure while using many libraries in Office Network. I was using Anthropic python library and when I execute the program, I started getting the error me

httpcore.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129).

Note: I had similar problem when I was trying to use yfinance library as well.

Most of the resource I found on the internet was referring to disable the SSL Verification when using the URLLib request. But in my case I am not using URL lib and I am directly accessing the anthropic library.